# F# SQL write an obj[][] to an SQL table

Tags: sql, arrays, f#, insert, ado.net

So I have an obj[][] that I've created using F# and now I want to write the values in that collection to an SQL table. The issue is this needs to be able to upload to any table that I specify. Meaning the name of the table is stored as a variable and the length of the collection will also change.

```
let tableName = "table2"
```

my object array is called dataTable so:

```
dataTable[0][0] = "Jackson"
         [0][1] = "Sentzke"
         [0][2] = "1991-04-19T00:00:00"
         [0][3] = "Jackson Sentzke"
         [1][0] = "Peter"
         [1][1] = "Sentzke"
         [1][2] = "1962-02-11T00:00:00"
         [1][3] = "Peter Sentzke"
```

This isn't how I actually get the values from dataTable, this is just an example.

Anyone know how I'd be able to insert the data from dataTable into "table2"?

At the moment I have:

```
let cn = new SqlConnection(connectionstring)
cn.Open()
let sQL = "INSERT INTO [" + tableName + "] VALUES(@param1)"
let db = new SqlCommand(sQL, cn)
db.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1", tableData)
db.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: F# exists independently of SQL and vice-versa. Retrieving values from an array has nothing to do with SQL. Inserting values into an SQL table has nothing to do with F#. What is your exact problem ?

Comment: Join the SQL room.

Comment: The answer to *this* question is the same as the original. That's not how SQL works. First try to write a correct INSERT statement, *then* try to execute this statement from code. The statement you wrote *still* writes only a single value to a table with only a single column.

Comment: Can you explain or show me how my insert statement is wrong? I've rarely done SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    let cn = new SqlConnection(connectionstring)
    cn.Open()

    for i=0 to tableData.Length-1 do
        let mutable columnsTemp = ""
        let mutable valuesTemp = ""
        for j = 0 to tableData.Item(i).Length-2 do
            columnsTemp <- columnsTemp + columnNames.GetValue(j).ToString() + ","
            valuesTemp <- valuesTemp + "'" + tableData.Item(i).GetValue(j).ToString() + "',"


        let columns = columnsTemp.Remove(columnsTemp.Length-1,1)
        let values = valuesTemp.Remove(valuesTemp.Length-1,1)
        let sQL = "INSERT INTO [" + tableName + "] (" + columns + ") VALUES (" + values + ")"
        let db = new SqlCommand(sQL, cn)
        db.ExecuteNonQuery()
```